# How to keeping header footer and changing main content?

Tags: php, html

I have created index file which looks like this

```
<php
    include 'HTMLS/header.html';
    include 'neworder.php';
    include 'HTMLS/fotter.html';
?>
```

The user start on neworder.html and from there he can choose to move to 4 different pages.
I would like to keep the header and footer on all pages.
how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the header, footer files on every page and change the content file

Page1

```
<php
    include 'HTMLS/header.html';
    include 'page1.php';
    include 'HTMLS/fotter.html';
?>
```

Page2

```
<php
    include 'HTMLS/header.html';
    include 'page2.php';
    include 'HTMLS/fotter.html';
?>
```

...etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-load the page you will have to accomplish this outside of your PHP code, e.g. by using Ajax requests.